# How to save a new value in external json file?

Tags: javascript, json

Let's say I have a json file called "abc.json"

abc.json:

```
{
    "one",
    "two"
}
```

and in the script, I am able to get the values from json file:

```
 $.getJSON( "abc.json", function( data ) {
         var items = [];
         $.each( data, function( key, val1 ) {
            items.push(val1);
         });

         //alert(items);
    });
```

What if I want to add "three" from the script (jQuery/Javascript) and it should be updated in the abc.json file?

I am new to json and I haven't seen any external json file storage in the previous posts.

Comment: I had tried local file system to do that in client side. Directly,it is not possible to modify the content of abc.json file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript can't access the abc.json file to modify/write to it.  You can load the json file, as you do, and modify the json in memory once loaded, but can't save it.  You'd have to write a small bit of code on your server to do such.